# Google Closure Template: how to create a plugin which prints HTML?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

I am trying to write a plugin for Templates which gives me the ability to write a predefined set of HTML and JS inside a {template}. Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to tell the compiler not to compile a `JsExpr` without using `soy.$$escapeHtml` in the generated JavaScript.

What I need is something like that:

```
{template .something}
  {myplugin('hello')}
{/template}
```

which in turn should be compiled into something like that (simplifying):

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script>jQuery('#hello').somePlugin();</script>
```

Unfortunately the compiled js *always* forces a soy.$$escapeHtml which prevents the plugin to work at all.

Comment: did you try with the flag `noAutoescape` ? https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands

Comment: @Hacketo this could be a solution (I will try it), but I am not sure if it's a good idea because the developer would need to remember to use that directive when using the plugin. The better option would be to be able to compile the soy file without the soy.$$escapehtml directly.

But maybe it's just impossible (without hacking the compiler, of course)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but If the developer use closure template and use your plugin, he should know that if the plugin return html, he have to escape it. In that way (you know that the developer must use noAutoescape), the plugin must care about escaping the content.

Comment: also, you could share a soy file with your plugin, with an `autoescape="false"` on all templates that need it. Then the developer will use `{call the.template /}` to incude a template. (Guessing)

Comment: It's definitely an option. I'll share this with the team :)

Thanks!